# Force TypeORM Enity.create to create one single instance of object

Tags: typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I am new to **typeORM** and I am making a basic *CRUD API* using the **Active-record** pattern.

I have a very basic entity and to save it to the database I use the following code:

```
const newUser = User.create(request.body)
```

But when I try to compile, User.create returns an User[] object instead of User.

If I call manually the method using the object, like `User.create({username: request.body.username, ... })` I get successully an `User`, but when I use `request.body` I always get an `User[]` regardless if I use the exact same object as the body of my request.

I checked the documentation and `User.create` in fact has a override that returns a single User, if an *object-like* parameter is passed, but produces a `User[]` if an *array-like* parameter is passed.

I've tried many thigs, like destructuring `User.create({... request.body})` and similar, but it does not work.

I think this is very confusing and prone to error, as `User.create` will behave differently using objects and the bodys request.

Does something like User.createOne() or something like that exist? so I can force the behavior to always create one single object?
I've not found anything.

Comment: Can you show us the `request.body` data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force it by casting the request body to an object first

```
const newUser = User.create(request.body) // User[]
const newUser = User.create(request.body as Object) // User
```

Comment: Wow... so simple but it works, thanks man!